# How can I fill very thin gaps between linoleum squares?

Tags: linoleum

I have a 20-year-old linoleum floor (squares glued down with mastic). It looks nice except in one area around the sink where the tiles might have shrunk.

There are thin gaps in this area, and they fill with dirt, leaving dark lines. I have tried some colored caulk made for this purpose, but the gaps are too thin to really get the caulk into. I have tried pushing the caulk into the seams with a knife, but I only end up with a THIN layer over the top of the gap which quickly shrinks or gets peeled away.

I am considering powdering a tile with a mortar and pestle then mixing the powder with wood glue. What do you think? Another idea is some kind of thin grout. Paint?

Ideas appreciated.

Comment: No matter what you use, you will have the same problem. The best option is to replace the tile. If you cant get the same colour, make it a feature. Get a patterned one